# Presenting & Closing a modal

Tags: ios, modal-dialog, react-native, reactjs

So I have an Initial Screen below which allows you to click on a button and present a modal screen:

```
import SettingsScreen from './SettingsScreen';
...
export default class InitialScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {modalVisible: false};
  }

  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
          <NavigationBar
            title={{ title: 'Initial Screen', tintColor:  'white', }}
            leftButton={
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)
              }}>
                <Image style={styles.leftButton} source={require('./../img/settings.png')} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            }
            rightButton={{ title: 'Forward', tintColor: 'white' }}
            style={{ backgroundColor: '#2196F3', }}
            statusBar={{ tintColor: '#1976D2', style: 'light-content' }}
          />
          <Modal
          animationType={"slide"}
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {alert("Modal has been closed.")}}
          >
          <SettingsScreen />          
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

It works, but now in my Modal screen I have a button which allows you to dismiss the modal:

```
import ...
export default class ModalScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                this.props.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)
              }}>
                <Image source={require('./../img/close.png')} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>  
        );
    }
}
```

But it's giving me an error saying `this.props.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)` is not a function.
How would I dismiss the modal within the ModalScreen?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should pass the **setModalVisible()** function to the modal component

Initial Component:

```
<ModalComponent closeModal={this.setModalVisible} />
```

and on ModalComponent call it like this:

```
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {  
        this.props.closeModal(false)
      }}>
    <Image source={require('./../img/close.png')} />
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

For custom functions in react native use ES6 style:

```
setModalVisible = (visible) => {
  this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
}
```

And the code should be: `this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)`